# PHP / JS Document viewer within browser

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have many different document filetypes that should be downloadable by users.  These include presentations, PDF, excel etc etc.  May also be mac filetypes too.

I'd like it to be possible if the user can view the document before downloading it.

I've hunted around but found nothing except extension specific posts.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to present content to a user:

- Content-Disposition: Attachment — which tells the browser that it should be saved rather then displayed
- Content-Disposition: Inline — which tells the browser that it should be displayed (either natively or with a plugin) rather then saved
- Via scripting / applets / Flash / etc — in which you provide program code to render the content

The first two approaches are generic HTTP. The third has to be handled on a file-type by file-type basis since you need different renderers for each kind of content.

Comment: Frequently, the easiest thing to do is to render them to images (using one of numerous tools). The user can get a preview by looking at the images on your site, or they can choose to download it if they'd prefer.

Comment: @ColinMorelli - Could any file or filetype be viewed as an image then? Can you recommend a tool?

Comment: You could create an image representation of most file formats, although some would make very little sense (e.g. the Apache HTTPD executable file). You would need to select tools on a filetype-by-filetype basis. Nobody has written a "Transform every possible input into a useful image" tool.

Comment: @quentin Thanks for the info.  I think I'll see about having an option for opening the file in the browser window or downloading instead of a view and focus on the main files such as presentations and pdf files.  Failing that a download will suffice.